# How to make a query to get average weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I have the following 2 tables which records every buying and selling of Goods as datetime

### 1- Selling Table

```
Date_of_Selling
------------------------------------------------------
15-09-2006
25-08-2007
13-08-2009
16-01-2009
22-01-2010
..
..
```

---

and here 2nd Table

### 2-Buying Table

```
Date_of_Buying
----------------------------------------------------
22-09-2004      
25-16-2006    
01-08-2010       
22-08-2010      
...
..
..
```

How can I find the average number of weeks between selling and buying ...
using timestampfunction or whatever ?
the result should be like : 5.3 weeks between selling and buying ,
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: what indicates that a certain buy and a certain sale form a "pair" and should be considered together?

Comment: I mean there are 2 tables to record income events and the other to record the outcome events..
and I need to measure the average response time between (income and outcome)
using the average number of weeks..

Comment: You don't have any identifier for the "product" being sold? You only have these dates?

Comment: And you also have a date of `25-16-2006`.

Comment: Say the date of buying in your example is 01-08-2010. What's the date of selling and why? If there is no logic to connect these two, then there can be no exact solution.

Comment: You need to show us all relevant columns in these two tables, and exactly what event each record represents. Are these files you are setting up, or that someone else created?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how fast a product is selling. In other words, how much days(or weeks) it takes to sell a product. If it is true, this SQL will give you the average days. You can devide it by 7 to get the weeks (I hope it works, I didn't try it, just improvising).

```
Select Date_of_Selling, Date_of_Buying, DAY(Date_of_Selling - Date_of_Buying)) as AverageDays 
from SellingTable ST
Inner join BuyingTable BT
On ST.ProductID = BT.ProductID
```

Comment: There is no indication how many records per product might exist in the file (or even if there is a product ID), so which of the records should you match up? The question is terribly vague on vital details necessary to answer the question.

Comment: I realized that you are right. Anyway, maybe it helps him. Do you think that I should delete my answer?

Comment: If there is exactly one record per product in each file, this query could help, but this seems very unlikely.  However, you might leave this as an incorrect, so that nobody else suggests it.

Comment: But suppose you wanted to match each purchase to the next sale date for that product.  Can you work out a query to solve it?